# Draw line from start of road to end given it's latlng

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'd like to highlight all roads around a user in a certain radius.

I've worked out how to get the lat/lng of the roads and even their lengths, but I'm struggling to work out how to draw lines from the start of a road to the end of the same road given only the lat/lng of said road.

```
countryCode:"GB"
distance:195.450718073417
gid:101823433
isIn:"Portsmouth"
lat:50.79336325
length:58.7727976883358
lng:-1.0940351000000001
name:"Colpoy Street"
oneWay:false
openstreetmapId:12929127
streetType:"RESIDENTIAL"
```

http://services.gisgraphy.com/street/streetsearch?format=json&lat=50.7913547&lng=-1.0944082&radius=200&streettype=&distance=true

I've seen various solutions of "snapping" to roads, but this requires a start and end lat/lng, I only have the single lat/lng of the road location.

I'm not fussy about the use of mapping API, although I'd prefer to use Leaflet.js/OSM. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific about your actual problem? Even [Leaflet's quickstart guide](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html) explains how to draw simple shapes.

Comment: Sure. So I have the lat/lng of a road. How can I draw a line that covers the entire length of that road? To plot a line I need a start and an end (with optional "road snapping"), but I can't work out how I would find out the road's start/end lat/lng.

Comment: If you don't already have the data there is no other possibility to set up your own routing server and fetch the closest roads e.g. via breadth first search. With GraphHopper this should be fairly easy to implement (there is no HTTP API for this 'exploration' yet)

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you. In your question you wrote *I've worked out how to get the lat/lng of the roads* so you already have the start and the end, don't you? The start and the end are always the first and the last node of a way in OSM.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm using this API to get roads around my position. It gives me only a single lat/lng http://services.gisgraphy.com/street/streetsearch?format=json&lat=50.7913547&lng=-1.0944082&radius=200&streettype=&distance=true

Comment: Not sure what this API actually does but it is impossible to describe a line by a single point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a server component that replys your request with the geometry of your desired road. For prototyping, you might use the [OverpassAPI](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) and display a geoJSON answer of the desired object in a new Leaflet layer.

Just to clarify: You need to add a new vector layer, as you have to use a seperate datasource with the road network on top of your raster maps.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. OverpassAPI even has the "around" style lookup so I don't need to use 2 API's either.